# Difference between these two requests

Tags: javascript, json

**Request One**  (Not working)

```
{
    "AddNewRequest":{
        "Patient":{
            "PrimaryPhoneNumber":" ",
            "DateOfBirth":" ",
            "CellPhoneNumber1":" ",
            "ResidentialAddress":{
                "AddressLine1":" ",
                "State":" ",
                "City":" ",
                "PostalCode":" "
            },
            "PhoneNumber1":" ",
            "SSN":" ",
            "FullName":"John",
            "Religion":" ",
            "Gender":" ",
            "Race":" ",
            "Firstname":"Vinoth",
            "EmailAddress1":" ",
            "LastName":"Cooper"
        },
        "Header":{
            "SourceSiteID":"300242",
            "DestinationSiteID":"300242",
            "PrimeSuiteUserID":"1"
        },
        "Credentials":{
            "VendorCredential":{
                "VendorLogin":"testGUID",
                "VendorPassword":"testGUID"
            },
            "PrimeSuiteCredential":{
                "PrimeSuiteUserPassword":"password",
                "PrimeSuiteSiteId":"1",
                "PrimeSuiteUserName":"Admin"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Request Two** (Working)

```
{
    "PatientAddNewRequest":{
        "Credentials":{
            "PrimeSuiteCredential":{
                "PrimeSuiteSiteId":"300242",
                "PrimeSuiteUserName":"Admin",
                "PrimeSuiteUserPassword":"password"
            },
            "VendorCredential":{
                "VendorLogin":"testGUID",
                "VendorPassword":"testGUID"
            }
        },
        "Header":{
            "DestinationSiteID":"300242",
            "PrimeSuiteUserID":"1",
            ":SourceSiteID":"300242"
        },
        "Patient":{
            "CellPhoneNumber1":"206-567-2222",
            "DateOfBirth":"/Date(1306348200000)/",
            "EmailAddress1":"JohnDoe@yahoo.com",
            "Firstname":"TestMan1",
            "FullName":"TestFullMan1",
            "Gender":"2",
            "LastName":"Testlastname1",
            "PhoneNumber1":"205-567-1111",
            "PrimaryPhoneNumber":"205-456-4545",
            "Race":"2",
            "Religion":"3",
            "ResidentialAddress":{
                "City":"Carrollton",
                "PostalCode":"35209",
                "State":"10"
            },
            "SSN":"911-91-9191"
        }
    }
}
```

I am just not able to figure out why the first request is not working and the second one gives response. Can anyone identify what i am doing wrong.

### Does Order Matter?

#### Update

The First one throws me *Bad Request* and the second one responds as expected.

Comment: can you give an example of how it isn't working?

Comment: @Jeff V: The First one throws me Bad Request and Second one gives me response back.

Comment: What kind of requests are these? They look like JSON strings. Are they being sent to a server? What software is the server running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JSON the order doesn't matter but the name does. In the **Request One** you have `"AddNewRequest"` while in **Request Two** you have `"PatientAddNewRequest"`.

Also on the server side, the serializer/de-serializer **may** need specific ordering.

[JSON](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627)

> An object is an unordered
>   collection of zero or more name/value 
>   pairs, where a name is a string and a
>   value is a string, number,    boolean,
>   null, object, or array.

Comment: You say it _does not_ matter and that it _may matter_? In fact id **does** matter and if you insist, even `{"AddNewRequest":{"PatientAddNewRequest":"whatever"}}` may give the same result as `{"PatientAddNewRequest":{"AddNewRequest":"whatever"}}` depending on the way request is processed on server side...

Comment: By definition the object in JSON is **unordered** collection of name value pairs. So from JSON perspective the order is not important. A serializer/de-serialize used on server side to convert from JSON string to another object or vice versa may depend on the order. A good implementation of serializer/de-serialize would not depend on it though.

Comment: I do not disagree with JSON specification :) I just mentioned, that in some implementations (obviously not following the JSON specification strictly) it may matter. Because we were not given any details about the server-side code (and we do not know whether it correctly implements JSON), I assumed it may be taken into account, thus _does_ matter. But I definitely agree the processing of the request should not depend on the order of properties.

Answer (score 2):

We do not know your code that is processing these "requests", but to answer your question:

**Yes, order of elements in JSON can matter**

...unless your code processes it in a way that is not influenced by the order of them.

For example, if you have two objects:

1. `{prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'xyz'}`
2. `{prop2: 'xyz', prop1: 'abc'}`

and you process them in the following way in PHP for example:

```
$data = json_decode($request_string);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo '['.$value.']';
}
```

you should receive following results:

1. for the first request: `[abc][xyz]`
2. for the second request: `[xyz][abc]`

but if you do it like that:

```
$data = json_decode($request_string);
echo '['.$data['prop1'].']['.$data['prop1'].']';
```

you will receive same result in both cases, that is:

```
[abc][xyz]
```

Hope that clarifies something.

Comment: I would oppose your answer that order matters. Intrinsically it doesn't and it shouldn't. But if your code is inter-related that doesn't mean that JSON property order is important. It means that your object order is important and their property definition. And writing improper converters isn't a wise thing to do either.

Comment: @Robert I agree it should not, but in fact it sometimes does. Answering the OP's question (which was interpreted by me as 'Can different order change anything?') though, the order of properties does matter (or more specifically: it _can_ matter). The problem is we were not given any details on server-side code, thus in this specific case - by saying that JSON properties' order _does not_ matter - we would skip some potential source of the problem. (Although I believe the source of the problem was the name of the property, not the order)

Comment: You've clarified your thinking and I think you should therefore state the same aspects in your answer. Change *does* to *can*. And yes. It does look like that the problem was in naming and nothing else.

Comment: @Robert It seems very reasonable - I have changed `does` to `can`. It should be now clear to the readers. Thanks, +1

Answer (score 1):

### Rename property name in #1 request

Have you tried renaming `AddNewRequest` to `PatientAddNewRequest` in the first request? Any difference?